# Developing Cross Platform App and Website using single framework

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, cross-platform, mobile-application

I have an assignment to work on a Cross Platform Mobile Application along with a normal Web site that can run in a Touch screen with bigger resolution. The web site and the application both should look alike with same functionality.

I am just wondering if any tool available to work on both Cross Platform Mobile Native app and  on the Web Site.

Thinking about PhoneGap with SenchTouch. But not sure whether we can build a website using it or not.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

With `PhoneGap` and `Sencha` do you making native app and can you MVC with theses. Or withs `Sencha, Web Server, javascript and CSS3` could you make web app. I hope help you. ;)